# Swagger UI + MVC 4 Web API Get JSON with object name

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I am using swagger ui plugin to document my web api. I want to return JSON object like:

```
{"Person": {
         "Id": 1,
         "Name": "John",
         "address": {
              "Street": "ABC",
              "City": "Penrith",
              "PostCode": 2034,
              "State": "NSW"
             },
         "DOB": "2013-11-11T00:00:00"
 }
}
```

Notice the Person object name.

I can do this with the following code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {

        Person person =  new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John", DOB = new DateTime(2013, 11, 11), address = new Address { City = "Penrith", State = "NSW", PostCode = 2034, Street = "ABC" } } ;

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { Person = person });
    }
```

Unfortunately, because the return type is HttpResponseMessage and not Person itself, Swagger just shows model as HttResponseMessage. That's not what I want.

If I change the return type to Person and return a person object, I don't get the the Person object name in the JSON return. That returns only -

```
{
     "Id": 1,
     "Name": "John",
     "address": {
          "Street": "ABC",
          "City": "Penrith",
          "PostCode": 2034,
          "State": "NSW"
         },
     "DOB": "2013-11-11T00:00:00"
```

}

Is there a way to return Person but have the JSON string with Person object name?

Comment: Where do you want to get the Person name? The JSON is simply a value which can be assigned to anything you want when you receive it on client side.

Comment: Look at SwaggerUI and how it needs a "model" defined.

Comment: Anyone can have the time to help you, but make things easier for them. I don't have the time to look at SwaggerUI. And perhaps many other people.

Comment: Fair enough. SwaggerUI needs the JSON structure to be "modelName" : { "property1": value, "property2" : value2} .. I am only able to do that if the return type is "HttpResponseMessage" from Web API. Swagger then thinks the model is HttpResponseMessage and not the actual model. If I set the return type to be "ModelName", then Web API creates JSON object with only key/value pair of the attributes of the model without specifying the model name. Then swagger looks at that and generates no documentation of the model's attribute and data type.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new class which has a Person property, instance it, assign the value to the Person property and return this object.

In this way, the JSON will look as expected.

If you don't want to create a new class, try using an anonymous type, like this:

```
// If you have this object
var MyPerson = ...;
// Return this from Web API
return new { Person = MyPersons };
```

(I don't know if this last option will work for you)

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. You've understood my question :) +1